# Spent time doing/ have no business doing something/ Have a job doing

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, participles

I do not really understand the use of participles in these kind of sentences.

> 1- We spent the first month just ***debating*** what to call
>   ourselves.
>
> 2- You had no business ***reading*** my private letters.
>
> 3- I have a job ***bussing*** tables at the coffe shop.

Are all of the sentences above missing out "in"

> 1'- We spent the first month just ***in*** ***debating*** what to call 
>   ourselves.
>
> 2'- You had no business ***in*** ***reading*** my private letter
>
> 3'- I have a job ***in*** ***bussing*** tables at the coffe shop.

---

> 4- I work at the coffee shop ***bussing*** tables.

I think the latter one okay to me(4). My interperation is something like that for the use of participle:

Bussing tables is part of working at the coffe shop.". In the process of working at the coffe shop, I am bussing the tables.

But I can't understand the use of the participle in the other sentences.

Answer (score 1):

These are correct without "in" and sound much more natural that way.  These examples are using gerunds, not participles.  To see that, note that the first two would work equally well with the infinitive:

We spent the first month just to debate what to call ourselves.

You had no business to read my private letters.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me what fuction of gerunds are these examples using? I have never come across something explains that kind of usage of gerunds. + Third example still seems awkward to me :(